# How to reduce the Committed Memory of an application?

Tags: windows, memory, ram

I have a game exe, and I want to reduce it's memory usage. I currently use EmptyWorkingSet function to keep Working Set around 10.000-50.000 KBs. However the system commits 1.000.000 KBs for the game. How can I reduce this amount programmatically (via windows dll functions etc.) or in any other way?

Image   PID Hard Faults/sec Commit (KB) Working Set (KB)    Shareable (KB)  Private (KB)

An Online Game.exe  3228    0   1.117.252   53.320  6.720   46.600

Comment: Is this actually a problem? High commit charge could just be the .NET framework reserving a lot of heap space for your application to improve performance.

Comment: but it affects the maximum ram I can use

Comment: Is this an application you've written yourself, or a third-party application?

Comment: it is just an online game exe like league of legends. third-party app.

Comment: Thank you for asking a **how** and *not* a **why** question. Too bad people can't commit to just doing what should be done (no pun intended).